# HC-05 Bluetooth receiver not working

Tags: android-bluetooth, 8051

I brought an HC-05 module. I used it twice or three times, it was working correctly, but now it is not blinking, can any one tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad or defected item, it happens often.

Maybe the electric power was no stable... or try it on another 8051 micro controller.

But if it blink that mean it's receiving power .. if not, buy another one:

http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20160518055547&SearchText=HC-05+module

Comment: Tony how can I check weather the module is working or not?

Comment: do you mean it's not blinking but still working ? like u can use the Bluetooth ! Mmmm can u see the connected device from other devices ?